# Looking for a VB6 grid that's a bit more than FlexGrid

Tags: vb6, grid

Really all I need is 2 columns.  The first column will have some text and the second column needs to have a combo box in it which will allow users to pick from it.

Bonus if the control is free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked out the [S-Grid](http://vbaccelerator.com/home/VB/Code/Controls/S_Grid_2/S_Grid_2/article.asp) from VBAccelerator?

Got a good performance comparison too - [article](http://vbaccelerator.com/home/VB/Code/Controls/S_Grid_2/Performance/article.asp).

Comment: Adding dropdowns is pretty straightforward.  I've used this a lot and love it.

Comment: Another vote for this control. It's very stable and robust. We use it at work to support lazy loading of datasets that are very large (would take ~50sec to load from a local SQL server instance)

Answer (score 2):

Isn't this what datagrid provides in VB6?

Comment: It does not provide any ability to do drop downs.

Comment: You will have to write code in focus related to events to put dropdown in cell & set the text of the cell when user chooses an item from the dropdown.

Answer (score 2):

We use the [VSFlexGrid](http://www.componentsource.com/products/componentone-vsflexgrid-pro/index.html), IIRC written by the people who wrote the MSFlexGrid which ships with Visual Studio but with more features, including in-cell combos.

On another project I wrote code to 'fake it' using a hidden combo and the free MSFlexGrid: in the grid's _Click event, move and size the combo to fit the cell (taking account of scroll bars if necessary), set the ZOrder (bring to front), make Visible and SetFocus.

Comment: Yeah, I have a project where I did that as well.  It just felt dirty at the time.

Answer (score 2):

Janus Grid (http://www.janusys.com/janus/library/HTMLFiles/GridEX2000/GridEX2000.htm), supports this, but it is not free

Answer (score 2):

Component One makes an all-powerful grid that we used all over the place. It's a great tool and we are very satisfied with it.

- Easy to use; extremely well thought out.
- Good help and documentation.
- It just works; we have not had any problems.
- The properties and methods make sense and do exactly what they're supposed to.

http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/VSFlexGridPro/

Here are some screen caps of the grid in our application:

[alt text http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/3339/tempwvr.jpg](http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/3339/tempwvr.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a free grid that is implemented as a single-file control with no dependencies. it is reasonably light weight and easy to implement.

[LynxGrid](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=70425&lngWId=1)

Comment: Don't people know what "implement" means?

Answer (score 0):

Know one more good 3rd-party grid control like FlexGrid. It's not free, but enough cheap and is still supported. It's iGrid from 10tec: http://10tec.com/activex-grid/

By the way, it's 1st version was based on vbAccelerator SGrid, but now it goes its own way ;)